# Continuous call to WCF service, the AVE time spend is different from single call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an WCF service hosted in my local, and I wrote a testing method to keep building web request to this service and track the time spend for each call, and then get the ave time. But it seems this number is not correct:

AVE time for 100 calls: 150 milliseconds,
Single call for a lot of times: 30 milliseconds.

If I debug in when continuously call the web service, I can get the correct response time which is around 30ms for that request call I stopped when debug, but once I remove the break point and press F5, the rest call again begin to use more than 100 ms...

Is that because the memory stuff in my local machine? or other reason to cause this?

Here is my code:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.Method = method;
            request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
            request.Timeout = 600000;
            request.Headers.Add("controldata", controldata);

            //add body if needed
            if (method == "POST" || method == "PUT")
            {
                if (requestBody != null)
                {
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
                    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    dataStream.Close();
                }
                else //allow post/put request send without request body
                {
                    request.ContentLength = 0;
                }
            }

            //get response
            Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            watch.Stop();
            timeSpend = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

then outer this part I have a loop for keep calling this part several times..

Comment: Are you hitting IIS?  Is it possible that an app pool is either starting up or recycling?

Comment: I'm using IIS Express to host the service when testing.. and why the time shows correctly when I debug into the loop?